# Open.prof files by snakeviz

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, python

I have few cProfile files which need to be opened in chrome.

The command to open cProfile files in chrome is `snakeviz fileName.prof`.

If i try to double click the .prof file & try to make it open by chrome, it downloads the file.

I want to always execute `snakeviz fileName.prof` command on every .prof file when double clicked.

I am currently running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

P.S. I have tried to edit dconf-editor settings but it did not seem to work.